# How to specify transitive dependency's version in maven?

Tags: maven

I have a dependency A which depend on B, while in A's pom file, B'version can be specified. So I want to know how can I specify B's version when building ? Thanks.

Comment: you want to specify B version "per build"? I mean running a build with B version 1.0 and another "run" with B version 2.0 ?

Comment: yes, that what I want.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in other answers "transient dependency" involve 3 artifact

- A depends on B
- B depends on C

so C is a transitive dependency of A

What you want is control version number of a dependency for each running build. To do so you should bind the version number of that particular dependency to a maven property

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
   
  

    <properties>
        <B_project_version>1.5</B_project_version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>${B_project_version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now you can pass a parameter to your build to specify the value of "B_project_version" for example

```
man package -DB_project_version=3.8
```

If you do not specify any value for the proper the default value ( 1.5 in the above example) will be used

It is handy to define profiles for *most likely scenarios* with the definition of apposite profiles

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>use_version_2</id>
        <properties>
            <B_project_version>2.0</B_project_version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>use_version_1</id>
        <properties>
            <B_project_version>1.0</B_project_version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If your intent is to control a true transitive dependacy you have to exclude it form B dependency in your pom and make it a **direct dependency.** The above example becomes

```
<properties>
    <C_project_version>1.5</C_project_version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>${C_project_version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>use_version_2</id>
        <properties>
            <C_project_version>2.0</C_project_version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>use_version_1</id>
        <properties>
            <C_project_version>1.0</C_project_version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Actually what I want is to specify C's version when building A

Comment: That would possibly break B/C compatibility. I edited the answer accordily

Comment: NB: just specifying the dependency version directly in your top-level pom isn't sufficient for accurate build reproducability as maven sees it as only a "soft" requirement and can still select a different version (e.g. for <version>1.2.3</version> it may select version "1.2.3.5"). So if you want to really control it you need to specify an a "hard requirement" with "[...]" syntax as per https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification

Answer (score 3):

To describe *transitive dependencies* we need three artifacts because its a dependency of a dependency.

Let's look at these three `pom.xml` files:

`a/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x.y</groupId>
            <artifactId>b</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>x.y</groupId>
                <artifactId>c</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

`b/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x.y</groupId>
            <artifactId>c</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

`c/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>c</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

In this example artifact `a` depends on `b` and artifact `b` depends on `c`.

Without the `<dependencyManagement>` block in `a/pom.xml` the artifacts `b` and `c` will be used in version `2.0-SNAPSHOT` but with this "*override*" the artifact uses `b` in version `2.0-SNAPSHOT` but the transitive dependency `c` in version `1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Maven will use the "nearest" version. So if you define the dependency to B and its version in your own pom, that will replace the one from A.

This might break A depending on how A uses B - since only one version will end up in the project and if B breaks some of its API you are doomed. There is only try and error.

See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html for more details on how maven resolves dependencies.